# Asynchronous code vs multiple processes for starter project

Tags: heroku

I understand that multiple processes (worker processes) can be used in order to offload the web processes of an Heroku app, before my app gets a lot of traffic, would it make sense to keep the potentially blocking tasks to some separate threads and calling them asynchronously instead of using multiple processes?

I see no reason why this would be a problematic approach in the beginning, but I was wondering if there is some reasons I didn't thought about that would not make it a good decision to start like that?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered containers or aws' lambdas for spinning off worker processes? Not sure what you want to achieve because the threads part is misleading.

Comment: @user2347763 Say we have funcA taking a request in argument and returning a HTTP response, let's say that client requested some data requiring to call funcB, but that funcB may take a lot of time to complete, I am wondering if this is a good approach to call funcB asynchronously before putting it to a different process